# How to implement an optional callback from scratch in Kotlin?

Tags: android, class, kotlin, callback, option-type

I have this function, which works wonderfully.

```
inline fun <reified T:Any>String.parse() : T {
    return GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create().fromJson<T>(this, T::class.java)
}

fun request (callback: (MyClass)->Unit) {
    val url = URL("someurl").readText()
    val myObject : MyClass = str.parse()
    callback(myObject)
}

net.request {
    it.myFunction()
    println (it.myString)
}
```

`myObject` automatically filled with an object of type MyClass, and returned correctly to the callback.

Now I want to catch the error, and have the callback can return it as well.

```
fun request (callback: (MyClass?, Exception?)->Unit) {
    try {
        val url = URL("someurl").readText()
        val myObject : MyClass = str.parse()
        callback(myObject, null)
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        callback(null, e)
    }
}

net.request { response, error ->
    if (response != null ) { // do something }
    else { // report something }
}
```

But this is ugly, because no matter what, I will have to force the callback to always have two parameters, but only one is present at a time. So I'm searching for optional callback methods. I want to be able to call the method like this:

```
net.request { 
    onSuccess { response -> // do something }
    onError { error -> // report something }
}
```

Or probably:

```
net.request
    .onSuccess { response -> // do something }
    .onError { error -> // report something }
```

If I don't want to handle the error, I simply make a call like this:

```
net.request {
    onSuccess { // do something with 'it' }
}
```

What I can found over the internet is overwriting the existing callback methods like [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/handsome-codes-with-kotlin-6e183db4c7e5). This is not what I want. I want to write that callback from scratch. Looking at the source code sometimes doesn't help either because the code is in Java, and I don't understand Java. Not yet.

And I understand that major library in Kotlin like retrofit or JavaRx probably already implement something like this, but I just want to know the bare minimum code needed to do this, as this is how I learn. I just can't find the correct tutorial for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [library](https://github.com/kittinunf/Result) out. It helps model success/failure operations concisely. Your callback can then take in your `MyClass` object wrapped this way `Result<MyClass, Exception>` or just `Result`.

To pass a value to your callback, you then do `Callback(Result.of(MyClass))` for a successful operation or a `Callback(Result.of(Exception()))` in case of a failure.

You can then consume the callback by using any of the functions below

```
//if successful
result.success {
}

//if failed
result.failure {
}

//fold is there, if you want to handle both success and failure
result.fold({ value ->
    //do something with value
}, { error ->
    //do something with error
})
```

Hope this helps :)

**Edit**: As @user2340612 pointed out, `Result` has been added to the Kotlin stdlib. See [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/index.html#result) for more details

Comment: `Result` is part of the Kotlin stdlib starting from version 1.3. Here's the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/index.html#result)